# Using Python 3 when Python 2.7 is default, pip install error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I originally had both python 2.7 and python 3 installed with python 2.7 as my default in PATH. I needed to run a script using python 3 but could not set it as my default python in PATH for some reason. After just uninstalling python 2.7 I opened 3 and ran the command python get-pip.py install which gave me this error

```
C:\Python30>python get-pip.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\temp\tmplqxvtx\pip.zip\pip\compat\__init__.py",     line 16, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name OrderedDict

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 19177, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\temp\tmplqxvtx\pip.zip\pip\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\temp\tmplqxvtx\pip.zip\pip\utils\__init__.py",     line 22, in <module>
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\temp\tmplqxvtx\pip.zip\pip\compat\__init__.py",     line 18, in <module>
  File    "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\temp\tmplqxvtx\pip.zip\pip\compat\ordereddict.py",     line 25, in <module>
ImportError: No module named UserDict
```

I already tried `python -m pip install` (module name) but it returns `No module named pip`

Comment: You're saying that you don't have `pip`. What did you expect would happen when you tried to install a module with `pip`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use windows, so here is an answer how to install pip on windows:

[how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

On Linux you could just type:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```